# Laravel 8 - count clicks but user can't spam the function

Tags: laravel

In my website I track clicks on a specific link and save the count on database with this function:

```
public function redirect($url)
{
  $data = Class::where('url', $url)->first('clicks');
  $cnt = $data->clicks;
  $cnt++;
  $sql = Class::where('url', $url)->update([
      'clicks' => $cnt,
  ]);
  if (!$sql) {
    abort(500);
  }
  return redirect('https://website.com/'.$url);
}
```

the problem is if someone spam the link , the count goes up. I want stop count if user clicked on link 5mins ago.

he will redirected to the link but count doesn't go up.

I'm new so it's so good if you explain it with details. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a new table, lets call it `link_clicks`. You will need 3 columns, one to identify the person, one to get the time and one to identify the link (I dont exactly know how you store the links you want to observe).
So more or less you will have the following table:

**link_clicks**

- user_id
- link_id
- created_at

If the users are always logged in, I would store the user_id, if they are not logged in, I would store the IP-address. So instead of user_id make a column called ip or ip-address.

Afterwards you can easily get the last click and its time.

**--Example**

Your new table contains following entry:
user_id = 1, link_id = 1 and created_at = 2021-04-21 19:00:00

Now in your controller you get the current date_time `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` and the user id like that: `auth()->id()`. You can also define your time treshold in minutes e.g `max_dif = 5`.

Afterwards you can query the table for all clicks for the user. You can either make the time comparision in your where() statement or you can make some comaprison in your php code to check if the time treshhold is reached.

Comment: it's a good way for doing this. but how can i compare the times??

Comment: You get the last entry of the user in the links_clicks table. This will be for example: 2021-04-21 19:00:00 , then you get your current date_time in your controller and if the difference is bigger than for example 5 minutes you can add one